YUM install of cassandra-3.11.17 returns timeout errors
I am trying to install cassandra version 3.11.17 by configuring the yum repo on amazon linux2 ,which it worked fine for earlier version of 3.11.XX. All of a sudden from 1-2 months I am facing timeout errors.When called from jenkins job for building ami it is always failing.
Repo used :
[cassandra]
name=Apache Cassandra
baseurl=https://redhat.cassandra.apache.org/311x/
gpgcheck=1
repo_gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://downloads.apache.org/cassandra/KEYS


Errors receiving :
[1;31m2024-08-14T06:27:37Z: ==> amazon-ebs.linux: https://redhat.cassandra.apache.org/311x/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on https://redhat.cassandra.apache.org/311x/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'SSL connection timeout')[0m
[1;31m2024-08-14T06:27:37Z: ==> amazon-ebs.linux: Trying other mirror.[0m
[1;31m2024-08-14T06:27:42Z: ==> amazon-ebs.linux: https://redhat.cassandra.apache.org/311x/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on https://redhat.cassandra.apache.org/311x/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'Failed to connect to redhat.cassandra.apache.org port 443 after 5001 ms: Timeout was reached')[0m
[1;31m2024-08-14T06:27:42Z: ==> amazon-ebs.linux: Trying other mirror.[0m
[1;31m2024-08-14T06:27:47Z: ==> amazon-ebs.linux: https://redhat.cassandra.apache.org/311x/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on https://redhat.cassandra.apache.org/311x/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'SSL connection timeout')

Is there any way that I can fix the timeout issue for installing cassandra 3.11.17 version.

The subdomain redhat.cassandra.apache.org redirects to the RPM repository https://apache.jfrog.io/artifactory/cassandra-rpm/ (INFRA-23511) hosted on Apache's JFrog Artifactory server relocated in July 2022 (CASSANDRA-17748).
Unfortunately, the Apache infrastructure where the redirects are configured has been experiencing issues last month (INFRA-25843) and earlier this week (INFRA-26034). It has been reported to the ASF Infrastructure team for resolution.
Thanks for your patience while we sort it out. Perhaps try again in a few hours to see it is working again. Cheers!
